# unique int id for a certain category in mysql

Tags: mysql

So the db structure looks like this

tablename(uniqueid, categoryname, categoryid)

I want to be able to generate a number that would be unique where categoryname="something"

Example, I can have the categoryname as 'something', and there are 5 different rows with the categoryid 1,2,3,4,5. and another categoryname as 'somethingelse', and there are 3 different rows categoryid of 1,2,3.

Since auto_increment wouldn't work, i was wondering if I can do that via php?

Comment: IF I understand you correctly, you need to take a look at [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)...  But I might not be understanding you correctly, so...

Comment: auto_increment field should work for you,. cz as i see it there is going to be exactly one record for every category in your category table.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you just need to get auto-increment to work, are you sure that the `uniqueid` column is set as the `primary key`?

Also, why do you have both `uniqueid` and `categoryid`?

For example, your table creation query should have looked something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

auto-increment can only be set on the `primary key` of the database table and it can only be set on one column.

there is much more info about auto-increment in the MySQL doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: uniqueid is unique to the entire table, categoryid is only unique to the category, which is specified by category name.